# How to generate Signed URL for google cloud storage objects using PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

The method i tried using was with openssl

```
$fp = fopen($key, 'r');  //open the PEM file
$priv_key = fread($fp,8192);
fclose($fp);
$pkeyid = openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key,"password");

openssl_sign($response["data_to_sign"], $signature, $pkeyid,'sha256');

$sign = base64_encode($signature)
```

**Is this the correct Method to generate signature for signed urls in google?**

Answer (score 12):

You can try Google Cloud Storage PHP SDK, it's a good choice for keeping your codes clean.

### cloud-storage PHP SDK

Install package to your project by following this page
[on Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/google/cloud-storage),
then

```
function getSignedGcsUrl($objPath/* which is your target object path */, $duration = 50) 
{
    $storageClient = new StorageClient([
        'projectId' => /* your gcp projectId here */,
        'keyFilePath' => /* your gcp keyFilePath here */,
    ]);
    $bucket = $storageClient->bucket($objPath);
    $object = $bucket->object();
    $url = $object->signedUrl(new \DateTime('+ ' . $duration . ' seconds'));
    return $url;
}
```

### laravel-google-cloud-storage (for Laravel)

Install and configurate superbalist/laravel-google-cloud-storage by following this page:
[on Github](https://github.com/Superbalist/laravel-google-cloud-storage),
then

```
public static function getSignedGcsUrl($objPath, $duration = 50)
{
    return Storage::disk('gcs'/* following your filesystem configuration */)
        ->getAdapter()
        ->getBucket()
        ->object($objPath)
        ->signedUrl(new \DateTime('+ ' . $duration . ' seconds'));
}
```

Comment: most accurate answer in 2019

Comment: Worked like a charm for laravel

Answer (score 4):

I put all the answers together. This should work in out of the box project. If you have space in the paths, you will need to `rawurlencode` the individual components, not `urlencode`.

```
function signedGoogleStorageURL($bucketName, $resourcePath, $duration = 10, $method = 'GET')
{
    $expires = time() + $duration;
    $content_type = ($method == 'PUT') ? 'application/x-www-form-
    urlencoded' : '';
    $to_sign = ($method . "\n" .
                /* Content-MD5 */ "\n" .
                $content_type . "\n" .
                $expires . "\n" .
                "/" . $bucketName . $resourcePath);

    $sign_result = AppIdentityService::signForApp($to_sign);
    $signature = urlencode(base64_encode($sign_result['signature']));
    $email = AppIdentityService::getServiceAccountName();

    return ('https://storage.googleapis.com/' . $bucketName .
            $resourcePath .
            '?GoogleAccessId=' . $email .
            '&Expires=' . $expires .
            '&Signature=' . $signature);
}

$signedPath = signedGoogleStorageURL(AppIdentityService::getDefaultVersionHostname(), "/my_folder/my_file", 60);
```

Answer (score 3):

One thing to note that I spent about two hours on:

The GoogleAccessId you pass into the URL is the Email Address in the "Certificate" section of the Google Cloud Console. It's not the OAuth Client ID with a string replacement as Google suggests in their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There's an example here that signs a URL for Google Cloud Storage using PHP:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-api-php-client/jaRYDWdpteQ/xbNTLfDhUggJ

However - I note this is tagged with Google App Engine... If your code is running inside of Google App Engine, you should use the built-in App Identity service - (note this will only work once your application is deployed in production, not while running locally) - this means you will not need to download or handle any private keys:

```
require_once 'google/appengine/api/app_identity/AppIdentityService.php';

$sign_result = AppIdentityService::signForApp( $message );
```

You will need to make sure that the service account associated with the App Engine application is added to the team for the project that owns the Cloud Storage bucket.

Comment: what is the method when not using google app engine?

Comment: Create a service account with a private key that is downloaded (see https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount).  That private key can be used to sign data in the same manner.  The link to the Google Group forum above shows how to use openssl_sign to accomplish that. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php shows an example of how to read in the private key file.

Comment: On the part where it says, "* signature will go here*" what does it mean? I'm referring to the example you gave with the openssl_sign. (The thing I'm most confused about concerning the example, is what information you are supposed to insert)

Comment: Yes - that is confusing. Looking at the docs for openssl_sign it appears upon success it overwrites that value - that is PHP is passing that string by reference rather than value.  Does that make sense?