# Signing URLs with JWT for Google Cloud Storage using PHP

Tags: php, cloud, google-cloud-storage, google-api-php-client

I've just started to upgrade my Google Cloud Storage code from API version 1.0 to version 2.0 and I'm having some troubles.

With version 1.0 I used Signed URLs with great success, using .p12 files. However that's deprecated in the new version and I have to use Firebase/php-jwt instead, using JSON files.

The problem is that it's just not working, I get the error:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message>
<StringToSign>PUT

image/png
1483626991
/myBucket/folder/test.PNG</StringToSign></Error>
```

This is the simplified code used to sign it.

```
$string = ($method . "\n" .
          $contentMd5 . "\n" .
          $contentType . "\n" .
          $expiration . "\n" .
          $file);

$signedURL = base64_encode(Firebase\JWT\JWT::encode($string,
        file_get_contents($credentialsFilePath)));
```

After the signedURL is received I build an URL with the correct data. The only part I've changed from 1.0 and 2.0 is the part where you sign the URL. Furthermore I've checked that the string in "StringToSign"-field of the response is exactly the same as the one I'm signing.

In version 1.0 I signed the URL like this:

```
$signedURL = base64_encode((new Google_Signer_P12(
        file_get_contents($p12FilePath),
        'notasecret'
      ))->sign($string));
```

All of this leads me to believe that I'm singing the correct contents but using the JWT function the wrong way. Has anyone else done this? How did yo do it?

In case it's interesting this is the URL I build (works with 1.0):

```
$returnArr['url'] = "https://{$bucket}.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/"
    . $prefix . '/' . rawurlencode($file)
    . "?GoogleAccessId=" . rawurlencode($serviceEmail)
    . "&Expires={$expiration}"
    . "&Signature=" . rawurlencode($signature);
```

Comment: the code is going to be different for the json file vs the p12 file.  you cant feed the p12 jwt code the json file its the wrong format.   Cant be more help then that.   I know the client library supports it you just need to find the correct code.

Comment: What do you mean specifically? The file loaded is obliviously not a p12 file anymore and I've tried to adapt the code to sign the string with php-jwt. The rest of the code should be the same since in the end the signature generated is just a signature string in the url. The contents to sign shouldn't change either.

Comment: Try and Google something like php Google service account json. An example should pop up or just download the p12 file and use your old code

Comment: I've been using Google and Stack-overflow for the better part of the day trying to find a solution :/ I'm really contemplating using the old code, although it's a bit infuriating knowing that it's old and deprecated. There is also a few functions that's not in the old code.

Comment: Assigning bounty, as I also really need an answer to this question, and can't find it anywhere.

Comment: From the Google response I see that $contentMd5 is missing; did you leave it out intentionally in the sample or is it a bug in code?

Comment: If i recall correctly $contentMd5 isn't needed, is it?

Comment: @Finglish It is ridiculous that this is so hard. I've checked multiple times that I sign the exact same string in both the previous version and the new one. Leading me to believe that I'm using the JWT feature wrong. However I closely followed the changelog to migrate the code and there was only a replace of function that was need. This is puzzeling..

Comment: @Tallkotten  I feel your pain, hence adding a bounty.  I have spent hours googling for an answer, and I haven't yet seen one complete working example, so despite that fact it looks like it should be simple, it clearly isn't

Comment: The [`JWT::encode` documentation](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/blob/master/src/JWT.php#L137) suggests that the first argument to `JWT::encode()` should be an object or array, not a string.  That object is then [json-encoded](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/blob/master/src/JWT.php#L286) into a string.

Comment: Interesting, I will try this later today or this week and get back to you with the results! Thanks. Worst case scenario is that I have already tried it, I've been reading the documentation a few times myself. Hopefully I just missed it :)

Comment: @Nicholas I've tried passing it as an array now. Although with no success. I tried with both of these ways: 

   $data = [
    "HTTP_Verb" => $method,
    "Content_MD5" => $contentMd5,
    "Content_Type" => $contentType,
    "Expiration" => $expiration,
    "Canonicalized_Resource" => $file
   ];

and 

   $data = [
    $method . PHP_EOL,
    $contentMd5 . PHP_EOL,
    $contentType . PHP_EOL,
    $expiration . PHP_EOL,
    $file
   ];

Still can't seem to figure this out.. why do they make it so hard on us..

Comment: Forgot to mention, even just sending in the normal string as an array doesn't work. ie. $data = [$string];

Comment: @Finglish It seems that the current problem is knowing how Google wants me to sign the data. Are there any JWT claims I have to use or how does it work.. Worst of all I can't seem to find any hints in documentations or upgrade files (https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/UPGRADING.md)

Comment: Could you try using [`AppIdentityService::signForApp()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/appidentity/#asserting_identity_to_third-party_services) to sign?  It accepts an arbitrary [string of bytes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/refdocs/classes/google.appengine.api.app_identity.AppIdentityService#signforapp).  [This answer to a very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39189894/5317173) gives an example of how to do this and provides it in a neat function you can reuse.

Comment: Will do! I'll comment here again when i do, thank you yet again. @Nicholas

Comment: How did this end up working out for you, OP? Can you post a self answer at this time or are there more issues?

Comment: Hi, sorry I've been swamped with things to do primarily my thesis. I have this on my todo list and comment asap. I can probably make time for it this week (also i need to change my email here, not getting any notifications it seems) @Nick

Comment: @Tallkotten: no rush, glad to hear you've replied!

Comment: @Nick I will set a reminder for me to do it next week! :)

Comment: @Nick Interestingly they updated their documentation on Signed URLs to include the App Engine signage, unfortunately for me I don't deploy my website in App Engine.. So the above solution might very well work, but not for me. Closest I found are this JWT standard they follow: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4.1 and this documentation page https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/service-to-service-auth. I have emailed the creator of the previous P12 signer, hopefully he might be able to provide the structure that is needed to successfully sign with the JWT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source for that [JWT library](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/blob/master/src/JWT.php) the first thing that jumps out at me, and I see was noted in comments, is that your payload should be an array or object, not a string... "**JSON** web tokens".

```
* @param object|array  $payload    PHP object or array

public static function encode($payload, $key, $alg = 'HS256', $keyId = null, $head = null)
```

Second, it looks like you are double base64 encoding it... base128? :) 
The return value of `encode` should be the three Base64**url** strings concatenated together, so you shouldn't need to do it again.

I'd give this a try:

```
$payload = ['HTTP_Verb'              => $method,
            'Content_MD5'            => $contentMd5,
            'Content_Type'           => $contentType,
            'Expiration'             => $expiration,
            'Canonicalized_Resource' => $file];

$key = file_get_contents($credentialsFilePath);
$signedURL = Firebase\JWT\JWT::encode($payload, $key); //think base64_encode here is redundant.
```

Ref: [Overview of Signed URLs page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#string-components).  They sure don't explain things very well in those docs. 
I assume you've looked at SDK?

If you wanted to go the string route you would need to sign using RSA signatures with SHA256... `opensssl_sign` or also maybe easier to lean on [Google's PHP SDKs](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-php)?

**Later...**

OK, decided to test it. Saw Google Cloud had a free trial. Installed `gsutil`, read a bunch of docs. Damned if I understand this JWT approach though. Share if anyone can even provide the docs on that topic.

***This code works:***

```
<?php
$method = 'GET';
$expires = '1503532674';
$container = '/example-bucket/cat.jpeg';

$payload = "{$method}\n\n\n{$expires}\n{$container}";

//assume you have this 'json' formatted key too? Otherwise just load the private key file as is.
$key = file_get_contents('~/oas_private_key.json');
$key = json_decode($key, true);
$key = $key['private_key'];

//if sucessful the encypted string is assigned to $signature
openssl_sign($payload, $signature, $key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);

$signature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));    

die("https://storage.googleapis.com/{$container}?GoogleAccessId=oastest@foo.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires={$expires}&Signature={$signature}");
```

Finally no "SignatureDoesNotMatch" error! Personally I'd use the [**SDK**](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-storage/v1.1.3/storage%2Fstorageobject?method=signedUrl). Little bit of init and you can just do something like the following:

```
$url = $object->signedUrl(new Timestamp(new DateTime('tomorrow')), [
    'method' => 'PUT'
]);
```

It would also make upgrades easier in the future.

Comment: Hi! I will be sure to check this out this weekend! Thank you so much for taking our time, hopefully their documentation has gotten better since they first introduced this (at the time I had not even heard of JWT, got some more knowledge now). 

I agree that using the SDK might be easier, but if I am not mistaken there was something that I used that were not available in the SDK (I want to say that it wasn't possible to sign urls back when I looked at it).

As you said.. The JWT approach is so weird, would it really hurt them to provide a workable example?

Comment: No to sound like too much of a jerk but I don't think I'll invest time like this on a bounty again. Assume it was just not rewarded because of lack of upvotes or answer acceptance.

Comment: Sorry, I've been having tons of stuff to do, this has been sliding in between the cracks time and time again. Is there any way i can transfer it now?

Comment: Whenever I get the time I will continue to work off your example. Might include the SDK into the project, but that would require a more extensive rewrite of other parts as well :)

Comment: I ended up just using the SDK

Comment: Hey, been awhile but wanted to say I'm glad it got sorted in the end. Cheers.